# Is "It won't let me not." grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, negation

I found myself saying the following sentence the other day:

> I always fasten my seat belt because my car won't let me not — it starts beeping loudly.

If I were to use *allow* instead of *let*, I would say:

> I always fasten my seat belt because my car won't allow me not **to** — it starts beeping loudly.

The latter sentence sounds natural to me because of the additional *to* that makes it clear what *not* refers to. Since *let* takes the bare infinitive, I suppose that using *to* in the first sentence would be incorrect:

> I always fasten my seat belt because my car won't let me not **to** — it starts beeping loudly.

Wouldn't it?

What would you say about my first sentence? The words "won't let me not" sound strange to my ear. Is it grammatical? Is it clumsy? Is it perfectly natural? What is the general rule of using *let* + negative verb with the actual verb omitted?

Comment: *I always fasten my seat belt because my car won't let me do otherwise—it starts beeping loudly.*

Comment: @zpletan: Yeah, well, I suppose there are many "workarounds", as it were, but I am really interested in the grammatical aspect here - see the last sentence of my question.

Comment: I agree with @JSBangs, but I want to point out that part of "correct" is also wither you prefer a prescriptive or descriptive grammar.  Although in this case the first type allows it, the second type is more liberal and would because there are numerous examples of such use by native speakers or "it just sounds right" to one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you're saying is perfectly grammatically correct, and in my opinion it's completely natural. All you've committed is ellipsis of the phrase *fasten my seatbelt*:

> I always fasten my seat belt because my car won't let me not *fasten my seatbelt*.

This is different from the case with *allow*, because the verb *to let* takes as its complement a bare verb, without the infinitive marker *to*.

> I'll let you leave. (wrong: *I'll let you to leave.)
>
> The nurse won't let you not take your medicine. (wrong: *The nurse won't let you not to take your medicine.)

So when using ellipsis with the verb *let*, it's correct to leave off the infinitive marker *to*, and to place the negative *not* at the end if required.

Comment: Is the usage a double negative? If it is, does that matter in terms of grammaticality?

Comment: @zpletan How would that be a double negative? Yes, there are two negatives, but they have different and non-overlapping scopes.

Comment: Looked it up on Wikipedia (shoulda done this before). It says, "A double negative occurs when two forms of negation are used in the same sentence. . . . In most logics and some languages, double negatives cancel one another and produce an affirmative sense . . . ." This is what is happening here. Two negatives are being used to make the one positive statement, "I always buckle my seat belt because my car makes me do so."

Comment: @zpletan, okay, so it *is* a double-negative in that sense, but it's a deliberate double-negative whose composite meaning is clear.

Comment: Tangent: This is why I dislike those statements about a double negative being the same as a positive. Sure, in arithmetic, -(-2)=2. But there is a big difference between "You are allowed to faster your seatbelt" and "You are not allowed to not fasten your seatbelt". The first says you MAY, the second says you MUST. The NOTs don't simply cancel each other out.

Comment: @Jay, on the other hand, "You are not allowed to not fasten your seatbelt," *is* the same as the positive, "You must fasten your seatbelt." A double negative does make a positive statement, it's just that different wording is often (always?) required.

Comment: It's a ***[Compositional](http://www.class.uh.edu/cogsci/lang/entries/compositionality.html)*** Double Negative, what [Horn](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/HornBLS35Handout.pdf) calls _Duplex Negatio Affirmat_, in which the Double Negative Law (**¬(¬p) ≡ p**, or **ENNpp** in Łukasiewicz notation) figures prominently.

Comment: Noncompositional double negatives, like _He ain't got no money,_ are more the stuff that excite peevers. Many if not most languages allow negative concord like this (_Je ne regrette rien, No tiene nada_), whereas English professes not to, at least not where anybody can see it in writing.

Comment: @zpletan The concept is the same, but the connotations are different. If, for example, I was protesting that this was not a proper subject for government regulation, the "double negative" version would, I think, be more emphatic. "This room is not clean", "This room is filty", and "This room looks like a pig sty" express essentially the same idea, but with very different degrees of emphasis.

Comment: @Lawler Sure. But even there I think it's simplistic to apply the rules of arithmetic to language. If I say, "I will not, not I say, go with you", surely the double "not" does not mean that I AM going. Besides, while in arithmetic multiply two negatives gives a positive, adding two negatives gives a bigger negative.